# How to find T(n) of an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

```
k = 1                # 1 
while (k <= n):      # n + 1        
    j = 1            # n
    while (j <= n):    # log_2(n) + 1 ?
        j *= 2       # log_2(n)     ?
    k += 1           # n
```

What would be T(n) of this algorithm? Would it be T(n) = 3n +2log_2 n  + 3 ? Or would it be T(n) = 3n + 2n^2 + 3 ? All can find online is how to find O(n)

Comment: I think `while (j <=)` will throw an error because `j <=` is not a valid expression.

Comment: What do you mean by `T(n)`? Are you asking about the time complexity?

Comment: Is `while (j <=)` supposed to be `while (j <= k)`?

Comment: Time complexity yes. But not Big O notation. T(n) is the equation that gives you the exact amount of time the code will take to run given n.

Comment: `O(n)` is not something you find, it's a possible answer to "what is the complexity of this algorithm".

Comment: _the equation that gives you the exact amount of time the code will take to run given n_ Every CPU in the world will take a different amount of time.  I do not even understand what you are asking.

Comment: I think `T(n)` represents the exact number of statements/lines executed.

Comment: Multiply the T of the inner loop by the number of executions of the outer loop. Then add 2 for the initial assignment `k = 1` and the extra test of the `while` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your values for each statement are correct. So just add them up and multiply.

The T of the inner loop is

```
2 * log_2(n) + 1
```

Add the initialization of `j` and increment of `k` to get the T of the body of the outer loop as

```
2 * log_2(n) + 3
```

This is executed `n` times by the outer loop, resulting in

```
n * 2 * log_2(n) + 3 * n
```

Then add 1 for the initialization of `k`, and `n + 1` for the tests of the outer `while` condition, so the final T is

```
n * 2 * log_2(n) + 3 * n + 2
```